# Sorting a 2D Array c++

Tags: c, visual-c++

I am bubble sorting a 2D array that looks like this. I am confuse on how to make my largest value as 1 and make the 2nd row's value follow to 1st row's counterpart.

```
Input:
13 9 1 8 5
1  2 3 4 1

Actual output:
1 5 8 9 13 
1 2 3 4 1
```

This is the expected output that i am trying to make.

```
    Output:
    5 8 9 13 1
    1 4 2 1  1
```

Here is my code for sorting the cards (col = 5 and row = 2):

```
void sortedCards(int card[][col])
{
   int i, j, k, temp;

   printf("\n\nSorted Cards\n");

   for (k = 0; k < 10; k++)
   {
       for (i = 0; i < row - 1; i++)
       {
           for (j = 0; j < col - 1; j++)
           {
               if (card[i][j] >  card[i][j + 1])
               {
                   temp = card[i][j];
                   card[i][j] = card[i][j + 1];
                   card[i][j + 1] = temp;
               }
           }
       }
   }

   for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
   {
       if (i == 1)
       {
           printf("\n");
       }

       for (j = 0; j < col; j++)
       {
        printf("%i  ", card[i][j]);

       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your sorting is only dependent on the first row, there is no need to iterate through the second row. Just set both rows at the same time while checking the first row. 
Also, if you want 1 to be treated as larger than all other numbers, you need to add that to your Boolean logic. Adjusting your for loop like below should do it.

```
int j, k, temp, temp2;
for (k = 0; k < 10; k++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < col-1; j++) 
    {
        //here we only test row 0, and we check if the value is 1
        if (card[0][j] == 1 || (card[0][j] > card[0][j+1] && card[0][j+1] != 1))
        {
            //all other reassignment is the same but you do both rows at the same time
            temp = card[0][j];
            temp2 = card[1][j];

            card[0][j] = card[0][j + 1];
            card[1][j] = card[1][j + 1];

            card[0][j + 1] = temp;
            card[1][j + 1] = temp2;
        }
    }
}
```